# django form wizard: global name 'request' is not defined in done() method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard, formwizard

I am using django form wizard, which requires a done method as such.

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    #Making an instance of Location
    location = Location(    
        manager = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        #more stuff
    )
```

Except I am getting the following error:

```
global name 'request' is not defined on line (the line with manager assignment)
```

Not really sure what I could do to solve this problem. Should I just insert request into the done method? would that even make sense? How do other people handle this?

Comment: def done(self,request, form_list, **kwargs) in your parameter

Comment: I think you can use request by calling self.request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer the `request` as `self.request` in class based views and form wizard.
Update your line to

```
location = Location(             #-------v
    manager = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
    #more stuff
)
```